# Why is there an extra space in between a variable and punctuation in a string? Python

Tags: python

There is an extra space in the output of a string. This is the section of the code where it happens. It happens in the string of the function, nameConfirmation().

```
def chooseName():
    name = ""
    name = raw_input("Let's begin with your name. What is it? ")

    return name

def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    print ("Right... So your name is", name,".")
```

This is the output it gives.

```
Right... So your name is Raven .
```

How do I get rid of the space in between the name and the punctuation?

Comment: Set the `sep` parameter of the `print()` function to `''` but then you have to add a space after "is"

Comment: Same reason there's a space between `is` and `Raven`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append string with `+`.

```
print ("Right... So your name is", name + ".")
```

Output:

```
Right... So your name is Raven.
```

Comment: With raw_input, would it be necessary to use str(name) in order to concatenate? I'm not on a computer or I'd check.

Comment: @JosephRyle I verified with python2.7 that `str()` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I just haven't learned that in my class yet.

Comment: @Destiny It is also a useful trick that can be applied in C++. Welcome!

Answer (score 8):

If you use:

```
print ("Right... So your name is", name,".")
```

You will notice that the output is:

```
Right... So your name is Raven .
```

Look at `is` and `name` (`Raven`). You can note in the output an space (`is Raven`), that is because `print()` have a default argument called `sep` an by default it's `print("Right... So your name is", name,".", sep = ' ')`. That argument is an string that it's added at the end of each piece of string concatenated with a coma `,` in the `print` function.
So if you do `print('A','B')` it will be `A B`, because when you concatenate `A` and `B`, `print` will add  `' '` (and space) as glue.
You can configure it: `print('A','B', sep='glue')` would print `AglueB`!

To solve your problem you can do two options.

- Change `sep = ''` and add an space  after `is`: `print ("Right... So your name is ", name,".", sep='')`
- Or, concatenate using `+` the last two strings: `print ("Right... So your name is", name + ".")`

Also there are a lot of another ways like: (I ordered them by worst to best in *my subjetive opinion*...)

- `print("Right... So your name is %s." % name)`.
- `print("Right... So your name is {}.".format(name))`.
- `print(f"Right... So your name is {name}.")`

Link with documentation:

- [Python Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)
- [Python 3 Course](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php) (Use of `sep` and `,`, `+`, `%s`, `.format()`, `f-string` and use of string class)
- [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) (Basic and advanced use of `%s`, `%d`, `.format()`, value conversion, `datetime`, ).

**P.S**: This isn't part of the answer, it's just a note.

- `print (something)` don't need the space --> `print(something)`.
- Futhemorer `sep = ' '` there is also called `end = '\n'` that determine the end of a print (`\n` = new line).

**P.S 2**: Thanks [Ouss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686784/7655838) for the idea of add some documentations links. I've just learnt that you can do `print(%(key)s % mydict)`!

Comment: I like your answer. Very informative and complete. Please consider adding some links to references/tutorials on strings manipulation and formatting in python3 at the end of the answer!

Comment: @Ouss, ok, I will start searching!

Answer (score 2):

Use the string variable substitution with `%s` as in:

```
def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    print ("Right... So your name is %s." % name)
```

or use the `.format()` function that is a built-in method for `str` in:

```
def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    output = "Right... So your name is {}.".format(name)
    print(output)
```

or you could use the shorter `f""` format as in:

```
def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    print(f"Right... So your name is {name}.")
```

For more on string manipulation and formatting in Python3, Check the following:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-string-functions-in-python-3
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-working-with-strings-in-python-3
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3

Comment: you can just use f-strings rather than substitution, it takes less space and it's easier to read. `f"Right... So your name is {name}."`

Comment: Thank for the comment. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The comma indicates a continuation on the same line with a space in between (you'll notice there's a space between "is" and "Raven", even though neither string has one in there). If you want to remove the spaces, the usual way to concatenate strings is with a plus

**Edit**: Plus, not ampersand... stupid me

Comment: Maybe you are mixing up languages, an ampersand won't work here in Python

Answer (score 1):

Each argument passed through the print command is automatically separated by a space.  I see you're in python 2, and I use python 3, so I'm not sure if this solution will work, but you can try doing this:

```
print ("Right... So your name is ", name,".",sep='')
```

This basically (assuming it works in python 2 as well) changes the separation between arguments to no space instead of 1 space.

Comment: If `print` function is enabled, the `sep` parameter already works in 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The reason why does the code produces a extra space is because the default `sep` looks like this:

```
sep = ' '
```

And the seperator seperates the values/input because by default `sep` contains a space. So that's why even though you did not put a blank space it still does the job for you.

Just in case you don't know what is `sep`, it is a short form for *separator*.

There are 3 easy solutions to solve this problem:

- `\b` escape sequence.
- `'+'` string concatanation
- `sep=''`

---

1st Solution (`\b` escape sequence):

```
print ("Right... So your name is", name,"\b.")
```

2nd Solution (`'+'` string concatanation):

```
print ("Right... So your name is", name + ".")
```

3rd Solution (`sep=''`):

```
print ("Right... So your name is ", name,".",sep='')
```

All of them produces same output:

```
Right... So your name is Raven.
```